# How to read user input from stdin on the command line without displaying it?

Tags: command-line, lua, stdin

I would like to mimic the default way of hiding a password on Ubuntu (for example, when using a sudo command), preferably in Lua 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the Ubuntu way, but try this:

```
io.write("password: ")
io.flush()
os.execute("stty -echo")
password=io.read()
os.execute("stty echo")
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess this a way to do it.

Comment: Only thing worth knowing here is that should this get interrupted between the two calls to `stty` the terminal will stay in `-echo` mode (which might confuse someone).